# EAGLE tool to LTSpice

Tags: eaglecad, ltspice, cad

I want to use a CadSoft - EAGLE tool model in LTSpice. I can't seem to find a way to do it. I can open the file in LTSpice as a "code" file so I can easily make appropriate changes in it. The file code is:

```
# Created by Ultra Librarian Gold 5.3.88 Copyright Â© 1999-2010
# Tanvir Mohammed, Premier Farnell

Grid mil;
Set Wire_Bend 2;


Edit 'DIP254P762X533-8.pac';
Change Drill 39;
Pad '1' Square 0 R0 (-300 300);
Change Drill 39;
Pad '2' Round 0 R0 (-300 200);
Change Drill 39;
Pad '3' Round 0 R0 (-300 100);
Change Drill 39;
Pad '4' Round 0 R0 (-300 0);
Change Drill 39;
Pad '5' Round 0 R0 (0 0);
Change Drill 39;
Pad '6' Round 0 R0 (0 100);
Change Drill 39;
Pad '7' Round 0 R0 (0 200);
Change Drill 39;
Pad '8' Round 0 R0 (0 300);
Layer 21;
Wire 6 (-10 341) (-10 350);
Wire 6 (-10 241) (-10 259);
Wire 6 (-10 141) (-10 159);
Wire 6 (-10 41) (-10 59);
Wire 6 (-290 -41) (-290 -50);
Wire 6 (-290 -50) (-10 -50);
Wire 6 (-10 -50) (-10 -41);
Wire 6 (-10 350) (-290 350);
Wire 6 (-290 350) (-290 343);
Wire 6 (-290 257) (-290 241);
Wire 6 (-290 159) (-290 141);
Wire 6 (-290 59) (-290 41);
Change Size 50;
Change Ratio 6;
Text '*' SR0 (-323 334);
Layer 51;
Wire 6 (-290 280) (-290 320);
Wire 6 (-290 320) (-320 320);
Wire 6 (-320 320) (-320 280);
Wire 6 (-320 280) (-290 280);
Wire 6 (-290 180) (-290 220);
Wire 6 (-290 220) (-320 220);
Wire 6 (-320 220) (-320 180);
Wire 6 (-320 180) (-290 180);
Wire 6 (-290 80) (-290 120);
Wire 6 (-290 120) (-320 120);
Wire 6 (-320 120) (-320 80);
Wire 6 (-320 80) (-290 80);
Wire 6 (-290 -20) (-290 20);
Wire 6 (-290 20) (-320 19);
Wire 6 (-320 19) (-320 -20);
Wire 6 (-320 -20) (-290 -20);
Wire 6 (-10 20) (-10 -20);
Wire 6 (-10 -20) (20 -19);
Wire 6 (20 -19) (20 20);
Wire 6 (20 20) (-10 20);
Wire 6 (-10 120) (-10 80);
Wire 6 (-10 80) (20 81);
Wire 6 (20 81) (19 120);
Wire 6 (19 120) (-10 120);
Wire 6 (-10 220) (-10 180);
Wire 6 (-10 180) (19 180);
Wire 6 (19 180) (19 220);
Wire 6 (19 220) (-10 220);
Wire 6 (-10 320) (-10 280);
Wire 6 (-10 280) (19 280);
Wire 6 (19 280) (19 320);
Wire 6 (19 320) (-10 320);
Wire 6 (-290 -50) (-10 -50);
Wire 6 (-10 -50) (-10 350);
Wire 6 (-10 350) (-290 350);
Wire 6 (-290 350) (-290 -50);
Change Size 50;
Change Ratio 6;
Text '*' SR0 (-323 334);
Layer 25;
Change Size 82;
Change Ratio 10;
Text '>NAME' SR0 (-320 379);
Layer 27;
Change Size 82;
Change Ratio 10;
Text '>VALUE' SR0 (-382 -150);

Edit 'MCP6041-I/P.sym';
Layer 94;
Pin 'IN-' In None Middle R0 Both 0 (-700 0);
Pin 'IN+' In None Middle R0 Both 0 (-700 -100);
Pin 'VDD' Pwr None Middle R0 Both 0 (-700 -200);
Pin 'VSS' Pas None Middle R0 Both 0 (-700 -300);
Pin 'OUT' Out None Middle R180 Both 0 (700 0);
Pin 'NC_2' NC None Middle R180 Both 0 (700 -100);
Pin 'NC_3' NC None Middle R180 Both 0 (700 -200);
Pin 'NC' NC None Middle R180 Both 0 (700 -300);
Wire 16 (-500 300) (-500 -500);
Wire 16 (-500 -500) (500 -500);
Wire 16 (500 -500) (500 300);
Wire 16 (500 300) (-500 300);
Layer 97;
Layer 95;
Change Size 82;
Change Ratio 10;
Text '>NAME' SR0 (-188 353);
Layer 96;
Change Size 82;
Change Ratio 10;
Text '>VALUE' SR0 (-253 -599);

Edit 'MCP6041-I/P.dev';
Prefix 'U';
Description 'IC, OP-AMP, 14kHZ, 0.003V/Âµs';
Value Off;
Add MCP6041-I/P 'A' Next  0 (0 0);
Package 'DIP254P762X533-8';
Technology '';
Attribute Supplier 'Microchip';
Attribute MPN 'MCP6041-I/P';
Attribute OC_FARNELL '9758682';
Attribute OC_NEWARK '33C0873';
Attribute Package 'DIP-8';
Connect 'A.NC' '1';
Connect 'A.IN-' '2';
Connect 'A.IN+' '3';
Connect 'A.VSS' '4';
Connect 'A.NC_2' '5';
Connect 'A.OUT' '6';
Connect 'A.VDD' '7';
Connect 'A.NC_3' '8';
```

If anyone knows how to then feel free to share it.

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/xdissent/monowave-eagle/blob/master/User%20Language%20Programs/Eagle%20to%20Spice.ulp is a starting point, never liked Eagle, so I can't tell if that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Give up any thought that this would ever work in any sort of native way. LTSpice has its own built in schematic and symbol editors. Its behavioral models for components follow basic Spice compatible standards.

Now if you fully 100% grokked the schematic and symbol file formats that come out of your CAD package and if you likewise fully understood the schematic and symbol file formats of LTSpice then it may be possible to write a translator to convert from your CAD to LTSpice. Estimating whether this is feasible cannot be made unless the relationships are understood however. *(There is a reason that there is a healthy business environment for folks that provide such translators between various CAD packages).*